# Openmp with ofstream and system command

Tags: c++, system, openmp, stringstream, ofstream

I have a problem using openmp

In other action to parallelize, I need to read a file, edit the content and save it into another file to give the entrance an executable that I'm going launched

For performance reasons, the loop is actually a recursion is parallelized.

**The problem is that sometimes the input file that I wrote and closed is not readable by my external executable**

**Do you have an idea ?  Thank you**

To reproduce the problem in the simplest I've created a small program :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <fstream>
#include <omp.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int max = 1000;
    int N;
    int nthreads = 0;
    int threadid = 0;
    time_t t=time(NULL);
    stringstream  s;
    #pragma omp parallel private(threadid)
    {
        #pragma omp master
        {
            nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
            cout << endl << nthreads << " thread(s) disponible" << endl;
        }
        #pragma omp barrier
        threadid = omp_get_thread_num();
        #pragma omp critical
        {
            cout << "Thread " << threadid << " OK" << endl;
        }
    }
    ifstream f("R:\\SIM.net", ios::in);
    if (f)
    {
        s << f.rdbuf();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier d'entrée" << endl;
    }
    f.close();
    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic)
    for (N = 1; N <= max; N++)
    {
        ofstream o;
        string l = "R:\\SIM\\"+to_string(N) + ".net";
        o.open(l, ios::out | ios::trunc);
        if (o)
        {
            o <<  s.str();
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier de sortie" << endl;
        }
        o.close();
        string commande = "\"R:\\LTspiceIV\\scad3.exe\" -b "+l+" &";
        int retour=  system(commande.c_str());
    }
    #pragma omp barrier
    cout << "FIN" << endl << endl;
    cout << "Temps : " << difftime(time(NULL), t) << " s" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: R is a perfect soft Ram Disk

Comment: I do not have this problem with a single thread :   omp_set_num_threads(1)

Comment: IO is typically not possible to do in parallel without locking and critical regions like you do in the first parallel loop. And even if it is possible to create, you are not likely to get any benefit from running this in parallel because all of your threads must use the same pathway from your memory to your hard disk, creating contention.

Comment: hi,  
I do not expect to profit by parallelizing the file writing, but by launching the external application in parallel

Comment: creating parallel file still allows to save time :  50000 files :  24s with one thread, 9s with 4 thread,  I use RAM DISK, not an HDD

Answer (score 0):

thanks to your answer  NoseKnowsAll

In fact I've already tried adding a critical region but it is worse

4/1000 file not readable without critical, 
56/1000 file not readable with critical

```
for (N = 1; N <= max; N++)
{
    string l = "R:\\SIM\\"+to_string(N) + ".net";
    #pragma omp critical
    {
        ofstream o;
        o.open(l, ios::out | ios::trunc);
        if (o)
        {
            o <<  s.str();
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier de sortie" << endl;
        }
        o.close();
    }
    string commande = "\"R:\\LTspiceIV\\scad3.exe\" -b "+l+" &";
    int retour=  system(commande.c_str());
}
```